# Can we add a systematic WHERE clause to Entity Framework when it queries a DB table (IE Soft delete)?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, soft-delete

I have just added a IsValidRecord column to a MyClass SQL table.
It will be used as a logical delete / soft delete.
Now I need to update my application to only query the valid records based on the new column.

I use Entity Frameword DB first.
Our app uses a business layer that centralizes all methods fetching the MyClass items.
So I have updated all the methods that query the concerned table with the appropriate filter based on IsValid.
It works fine.

However, I am pretty sure that these are bad practises because devs will forget to set this filter on new methods that will be added in the future, which will obviously bring incorrect records.

I wonder if EF would have features to automatically filter the queries with the appropriate "AND IsValid = 1" filter?

I used to be working for a company doing the same with NHibernate.

The only supported feature that I have seen for EF is this:
[Soft Delete](https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/)
Unfortunately,it overwrites OnModelCreating so I take it that it only works for Code First architecture.
We use DataBase first so I think it does not work as OnModelCreating is never called?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.meziantou.net/2017/07/10/entity-framework-core-soft-delete-using-query-filters (although also this uses `OnModelCreating `)

Comment: This link is for Entity Framework Core. My app uses EF and I can't upgrade to EF Core. And yes, as far as I know, OnModelCreating is not executed in DB First architecture.

Comment: Why not just keep doing what you are currently doing until you move to Code First From Existing Database or EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

I would normally implement this filter using application-specific views in the database (after all, some uses of this data may need to be able to see deleted items).

With a simple definition for the view, they should automatically be considered updatable by SQL so you shouldn't need to have to write triggers to manage `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations. You then lie to Entity Framework about what its "tables" are and it should mostly be none-the-wiser.

Depending on how you want the soft-delete to work, you may choose to hide the existence of the `IsValidRow` column (nit: we have rows in SQL, not records) in this view and implement an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on the view allowing *your* application to soft delete these rows by asking EF to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The best link I have found is this:
[EDMX Mapping](https://benjaminet.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/handling-logical-delete-with-entity-framework-4/)
Use EDMX designer to add the filter condition. It's basically exacly what I want...

Are there any down sides for this solution?
At first sight, it sounds good enough to me.

Only disadvantage that I can think of is that the filter is well hidden. Other devs in the future might have very hard time to figure out why / where / how are the entities filtered.

Comment: The problem with this post as it currently stands is it's trying to be an answer *and* trying to clarify the question by asking if there are downsides. I would *probably* have made an edit to the question and once you've decided it *is* the approach you're using, add an answer then (it's a bit light on *details* to stand on its own as an answer too. [The "answer" shouldn't be in another "castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))